# Changing default value for published in website_hr Odoo module

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I've been trying for a while to make employees be published automatically on website Odoo module. However, when I add a new employee, published field is set to "Unpublished" by default. This causes the employee to appear on about us webpage but not being published. I'd like that field to have "Published" value by default, so that everyone can see this employee automatically.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Login with admin account, goto **Settings >> Activate developer mode**.

Goto employees menu, click on Debug icon >> Edit action.

Set **Context Value** field value `{'default_website_published': True}`.

Save and reload the app, create new employee and the employee will be setup as published automatically.
[image: New Employee]

Comment: can you check the screenshot and match with your new employee create form, from Employees menu? Note that New records are published by default.